# Как добавить less файл в уже загруженную страницу?

Tags: javascript, less

Как я понимаю, js модуль less'а компилирует все загруженные таблицы стилей при инициализации.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet/less" href="main.less">
<script src="less/dist/less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Но как заставить работать less файл, загруженный уже после инициализации модуля?

```
$('head').prepend('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet/less" href="another.less">');
```

Comment: А зачем вообще так делать? Компилируйте less заранее, при сборке проекта например. Или хотя бы на сервере, с кешированием..

Comment: Согласен с @Darth, по логике вашего подключения надо пересобирать вообще все less.

Comment: @Darth например пользователь нажал на активный элемент сайта и нужно загрузить новые стили. Сервер я не использую, работаю на фронте.

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev я надеялся на то, что у модуля less'а есть функция для компиляции .less файлов, которую я могу использовать в коде.

Comment: @Diskyp ок, допустим, но что мешает  иметь эти стили уже скомпилированными заранее?

Comment: @Diskup поставьте себе webpack (или gulp, или grunt), или компилируйте ручками из консоли - но у клиента в браузере этого точно не надо делать

Comment: @Darth наверное то, что я их постоянно меняю в процессе разработки и хочу, чтобы они компилировались автоматически. И без сервера. И даже после инициализации страницы.

Comment: Это лишняя нагрузка на браузер и медленный рендеринг, стоит оно того? используйте сборщики вроде gulp и все в один css

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev стандартная ситуация на стаке: спросил как сделать x, мне говорят что x ненужен, делай y. Я отвечаю, что мне нужен именно x, но гуру сего ресурса упорно гнут своё и говорят делать y, игнорируя суть моего вопроса. Пойду ещё где-нибудь поспрашиваю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пересмотрел код https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/3.x/dist/less.js#L750

Попробуйте:

```
// Я подгружал по клику.
//document.getElementById("clicker").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet/less");
    link.setAttribute("href", "/2.less");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
    // Сверху эквивалент 
    //$('head').prepend('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet/less" href="another.less">');

    less.registerStylesheetsImmediately();
    less.refresh(true, undefined ,true);
//});
```

Можно и без добавления элемента в **head**. Но не факт, что при обновлении библиотеки оно не перестанет работать.

```
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.setAttribute("href", "/2.less");

less.sheets.push(link);
less.refresh(true, undefined ,true);
```

Comment: Воу, спасибо, это то, что я тогда и искал.